# How to change the value of column that has a apostrophe

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I change the name of a value that contains an apostrophe?

I'm using the following code:

```
bak$country[bak$country=='Lao People's Dem.Rep' ] <- Laos
```

Problem is that RStudio miss interpret that as if I'm switching from integer to characters, which returns the following:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "bak$country[bak$country=='Lao People's"
```

How do I code it so RStudio recongize that the apostrophe is part of the name?

Comment: If you use double quotations instead of single quotations in the first line of code it should work fine.

Comment: use either `"Lao People's Dem.Rep"` or `'Lao People"s Dem.Rep'`

Comment: I thought I had already tried that, but it did the trick so I must have mistyped something previously. Thank you for response!

Comment: `sub("Lao People's Dem.Rep", "Laos", bak$country)` should also work.